# ¿Como realizo consulta a través de un combobox en JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, combobox

Buenas gente, estoy diseñando una interfaz en donde quiero que realice lo siguiente:

[image: Selección de combo]

Al seleccionar un ciclo se mostrarán los grados que sean del mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema radica en que sólo puedo hacer que cargue el grupo del primer registro y no encuentro como hacer que si selecciono otro ciclo aparezca los otros grados.

Mi código del CB es el siguiente:

```
rs = st.executeQuery("Select grado,grupo from grupos where id_ciclo = '" + this.jtf_id_ciclo.getText() + "';");
        while (rs.next()) {
            this.jcb_grado.addItem(rs.getString(1) + rs.getString(2));                                
        }
```

Espero haya sido claro. Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: this.jcb_grado.updateUI(); después del while, y como recomendación utiliza el preparedStatement en tu consulta, en un futuro alguien podrá hacerte SQLInjection en tus consultas cuando empieces a programar en servidores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si aseguras que al cambiar de elemento en el combobox del ciclo, construye correctamente el query y además obtiene datos:

```
rs = st.executeQuery("Select grado,grupo from grupos where id_ciclo = '" + this.jtf_id_ciclo.getText() + "';");
```

entonces para que al cambiar de ciclo y actualizar con nuevos datos el `combobox` llamado `jcb_grado` muestre los datos del ciclo seleccionado, borra los datos contenidos dentro de el:

```
   jcb_grado.getItems().clear();
```

y posteriormente agrega los nuevos:

```
  while (rs.next()) {
            this.jcb_grado.addItem(rs.getString(1) + rs.getString(2));                                
        }
```